# Initializing the nested anonymus struct created from XML to struct converter

Tags: go, struct

Following is the output from an XML to struct transform for Go

```
type Metadata struct {
XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"metadata"`
Text        string   `xml:",chardata"`
Ns2         string   `xml:"ns2,attr"`
PasMetadata struct {
    Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
    SimpleValue struct {
        Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
        Entry struct {
            Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
            Key   string `xml:"key"`
            Value string `xml:"value"`
        } `xml:"entry"`
    } `xml:"simple_value"`
} `xml:"pas_metadata"`}
```

but based on suggestion for nested anonymous struct created other struct as below

```
    type PasMetadata struct {
    Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
    SimpleValue `xml:"simple_value"`
}

type SimpleValue struct {
    Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
    Entry `xml:"entry"`
}

type Entry struct {
    Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
    Key   string `xml:"key"`
    Value string `xml:"value"`
}

type Metadata struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"metadata"`
    Text        string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Ns2         string   `xml:"ns2,attr"`
    PasMetadata `xml:"pas_metadata"`
}
```

Now getting error while initializing with following statement

```
metinfo := Metadata{Ns2: "http://test.com", PasMetadata{SimpleValue{Entry{Key: "testcode", Value: "testvalue"}}}}
```

Error was : mixture of field:value and value initializers

Comment: You can't mix `field:value` (i.e. `Ns2: "http://test.com"`) and `value` (i.e. `PasMetadata{...}`). Use either `field:value` for all fields in the composite literals, or `value` for all fields in the composite literal, but don't mix them. Using `field:value` allow you to initialize only those fields that you need, using `value` you need to initialize all fields.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/F1WSiK81S1K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of [embedded structs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) is similar to regular ones, see [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). If you specify a field name, you must specify all of them.

For embedded structs, the field name is the name of the embedded type.

So your composite literal becomes:

```
metinfo := Metadata{Ns2: "http://test.com", PasMetadata: PasMetadata{SimpleValue: SimpleValue{Entry: Entry{Key: "testcode", Value: "testvalue"}}}}
```

The difference from yours is that the field name is always set. Specifically:

- `PasMetadata: PasMetadata{...}`
- `SimpleValue: SimpleValue{...}`
- `Entry: Entry{...}`

Comment: just started to explore go. Thanks for the information and its working